# Stop script execution after refresh

Tags: javascript, refresh

I wrote a single program using html and javascript which contains a submit button. The problem that I have is that when I refresh my page, it's like I pressed submit button again!! But what I want is to NOT execut the script if I refresh the page. I don't know if it's clear but it's like that I want the program to get intialized if i refresh my page instead of executing a previous script !

Comment: We want help you, but need a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue. If You take a moment to write a complete example of that behavior is more likely that you get the correct answer.

Comment: I think that there is a php code that you didn't provide. In that case you have to clear post data in php or redirect again to the same page (what does the same thing) after this code. Otherwise I don't know what is the purpose of this code.

Comment: Seems like there is missing some code. Also, do you have to reload the page for this to work, or could you preventDefault action with JavaScript and fetch the necessary variables then?

Comment: If you don't provide us any of your code, it is not easy to help you find where your mistake is.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to the browser behaviour that is when you submit a form to the same page, if you refresh it will prompt you to resubmit the data again.

You can avoid this by issuing a redirect at the end of your script, to refresh the page and clear the history of the submit.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // ... your code here

    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```